# ssh -L forward multiple ports

Tags: ssh, port, portforwarding

I'm currently running a bunch of:

```
sudo ssh -L PORT:IP:PORT root@IP
```

where IP is the target of a secured machine, and PORT represents the ports I'm forwarding.

This is because I use a lot of applications which I cannot access without this forwarding. After performing this, I can access through `localhost:PORT`.

The main problem occured now that I actually have 4 of these ports that I have to forward.

My solution is to open 4 shells and constantly search my history backwards to look for exactly which ports need to be forwarded etc, and then run this command - one in each shell (having to fill in passwords etc).

If only I could do something like:

```
sudo ssh -L PORT1+PORT2+PORT+3:IP:PORT+PORT2+PORT3 root@IP
```

then that would already really help.

Is there a way to make it easier to do this?

Answer (score 402, accepted):

The `-L` option can be specified multiple times within the same command. Every time with different ports. I.e. `ssh -L localPort0:ip:remotePort0 -L localPort1:ip:remotePort1 ...`

Comment: At first I didn't understand this answer. So posting an example here in case anyone suffers the same. The author meant "ssh -L port0:ip:port0 -L port1:ip:port1 ..."

Comment: And of course the port on the left side is local, on the right side remote. Ex. ssh -L localPort0:IP:remotePort0 -L localPort1:IP:remotePort1

Comment: Can this be done with a reverse tunnel also?

Comment: @DarkStar1 yes! I just tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 124):

Exactly what [NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3751845/nan) answered, you specify multiple -L arguments. I do this all the time. Here is an example of multi port forwarding:

```
ssh remote-host -L 8822:REMOTE_IP_1:22 -L 9922:REMOTE_IP_2:22
```

**Note**: This is same as  `-L localhost:8822:REMOTE_IP_1:22` if you don't specify `localhost`.

Now with this, you can now (from another terminal) do:

```
ssh localhost -p 8822
```

to connect to `REMOTE_IP_1` on port `22`

and similarly

```
ssh localhost -p 9922
```

to connect to `REMOTE_IP_2` on port `22`

Of course, there is nothing stopping you from wrapping this into a script or automate it if you have many different host/ports to forward and to certain specific ones.

Comment: Be careful about this: "Note: This is same as  -L localhost:8822:REMOTE_IP_1:22 if you don't specify localhost." 

This is only true if the GatewayPorts setting is 'no', which is admittedly the default. But considering the implications if it's not, you should verify the setting or, better still, be explicit and use "-L localhost:8822...".

Comment: I agree with @David `By default, anyone (even on different machines) can connect to the specified port on the SSH client machine. However, this can be restricted to programs on the same host by supplying a bind address: ssh -L 127.0.0.1:80:intra.example.com:80 gw.example.com` https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Answer (score 67):

For people who are forwarding multiple ports through ***the same host*** can set up something like this in their *~/.ssh/config*

```bash
Host all-port-forwards
  Hostname 10.122.0.3
  User username
  LocalForward PORT_1 IP:PORT_1
  LocalForward PORT_2 IP:PORT_2
  LocalForward PORT_3 IP:PORT_3
  LocalForward PORT_4 IP:PORT_4
```

and it becomes a simple `ssh all-port-forwards` away.

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: This is by far the best method, and I'd guess most users will have just one remote server with nginx proxies to access their CGNAT-shielded home ports etc.

Comment: ( of course, just to be complete, the example I just mentioned is with the -R instead of -L option, i.e. RemoteForward instead of LocalForward )

Answer (score 32):

You can use the following bash function (just add it to your `~/.bashrc`):

```
function pfwd {
  for i in ${@:2}
  do
    echo Forwarding port $i
    ssh -N -L $i:localhost:$i $1 &
  done  
}
```

Usage example:

```
pfwd hostname {6000..6009}
```

Comment: Use `-f` to run in background

Comment: Ehmmm... why do you want do it in that way?

Comment: That opens a separate tunnel for each port.  Not efficient.

Answer (score 9):

jbchichoko and yuval have given viable solutions. But jbchichoko's answer isn't a flexible answer as a function, and the opened tunnels by yuval's answer cannot be shut down by `ctrl+c` because it runs in the background. I give my solution below solving both the two flaws:

**Defing a function in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`**:

```
# fsshmap multiple ports
function fsshmap() {
  echo -n "-L 1$1:127.0.0.1:$1 " > $HOME/sh/sshports.txt
  for ((i=($1+1);i<$2;i++))
  do
    echo -n "-L 1$i:127.0.0.1:$i " >> $HOME/sh/sshports.txt
  done
  line=$(head -n 1 $HOME/sh/sshports.txt)
  cline="ssh "$3" "$line
  echo $cline
  eval $cline
}
```

**A example of running the function:**

```
fsshmap 6000 6010 hostname
```

**Result of this example:**

You can access `127.0.0.1:16000~16009` the same as `hostname:6000~6009`

Answer (score 7):

In my company both me and my team members need access to 3 ports of a non-reachable "target" server so I created a **permanent tunnel** (that is a tunnel that can run **in background** indefinitely, see params [`-f`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#f) and [`-N`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#N)) from a reachable server to the target one.  On the command line of the reachable server I executed:

```
ssh root@reachableIP -f -N  -L *:8822:targetIP:22  -L *:9006:targetIP:9006  -L *:9100:targetIP:9100
```

I used user `root` but your own user will work.  You will have to enter the password of the chosen user (even if you are already connected to the reachable server with that user).

Now port 8822 of the reachable machine corresponds to port 22 of the target one (for ssh/PuTTY/WinSCP) and ports 9006 and 9100 on the reachable machine correspond to the same ports of the target one (they host two web services in my case).

Answer (score 5):

Another one liner that I use and works on debian:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 $(for j in $(seq 20000 1 20100 ) ; do  echo " -L$j:127.0.0.1:$j " ; done | tr -d "\n")
```

Comment: BTW I don't think you need the `tr -d "\n"` at the end. For me, the subshell simply parses into new args. Something like this works for me (for Jupyter notebooks): `ssh somewhere $(for i in $(seq 8888 8898); do echo "-L ${i}:localhost:${i}"; done)`

Answer (score 3):

One of the benefits of logging into a server with port forwarding is facilitating the use of Jupyter Notebook. This [link](https://medium.com/@sankarshan7/how-to-run-jupyter-notebook-in-server-which-is-at-multi-hop-distance-a02bc8e78314) provides an excellent description of how to it. Here I would like to do some summary and expansion for all of you guys to refer.

Situation 1. Login from a local machine named Host-A (e.g. your own laptop) to a remote work machine named Host-B.

```
ssh user@Host-B -L port_A:localhost:port_B
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='' --no-browser --port=port_B
```

Then you can open a browser and enter: http://localhost:port_A/ to do your work on Host-B but see it in Host-A.

Situation 2. Login from a local machine named Host-A (e.g. your own laptop) to a remote login machine named Host-B and from there login to the remote work machine named Host-C. This is usually the case for most analytical servers within universities and can be achieved by using two `ssh -L` connected with `-t`.

```
ssh -L port_A:localhost:port_B user@Host-B -t ssh -L port_B:localhost:port_C user@Host-C
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='' --no-browser --port=port_C
```

Then you can open a browser and enter: http://localhost:port_A/ to do your work on Host-C but see it in Host-A.

Situation 3. Login from a local machine named Host-A (e.g. your own laptop) to a remote login machine named Host-B and from there login to the remote work machine named Host-C and finally login to the remote work machine Host-D. This is not usually the case but might happen sometime. It's an extension of Situation 2 and the same logic can be applied on more machines.

```
ssh -L port_A:localhost:port_B user@Host-B -t ssh -L port_B:localhost:port_C user@Host-C -t ssh -L port_C:localhost:port_D user@Host-D
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='' --no-browser --port=port_D
```

Then you can open a browser and enter: http://localhost:port_A/ to do your work on Host-D but see it in Host-A.

Note that port_A, port_B, port_C, port_D can be random numbers except common port numbers listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Common_port_numbers). In Situation 1, port_A and port_B can be the same to simplify the procedure.

Comment: A reminder, same port on different servers are different ports. Hence it could always make things easier by specifying an identical port number!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution inspired from the one from Yuval Atzmon.

It has a few benefits over the initial solution:

- first it creates a single background process and not one per port
- it generates the alias that allows you to kill your tunnels
- it binds only to 127.0.0.1 which is a little more secure

You may use it as:

- tnl your.remote.com 1234
- tnl your.remote.com {1234,1235}
- tnl your.remote.com {1234..1236}

And finally kill them all with `tnlkill`.

```
function tnl {
  TUNNEL="ssh -N "
  echo Port forwarding for ports:
  for i in ${@:2}
  do
    echo " - $i"
    TUNNEL="$TUNNEL -L 127.0.0.1:$i:localhost:$i"
  done
  TUNNEL="$TUNNEL $1"
  $TUNNEL &
  PID=$!
  alias tnlkill="kill $PID && unalias tnlkill"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to tell `ssh` to work as a SOCKS proxy using the `-D` flag.

That way you would be able to connect to any remote network address/port accesible through the ssh server as long as the client applications are able to go through a SOCKS proxy (or work with something like [`socksify`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple solution that runs in the background and is easy to kill - use a control socket

```
# start
$ ssh -f -N -M -S $SOCKET -L localhost:9200:localhost:9200 $HOST
# stop
$ ssh -S $SOCKET -O exit $HOST
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed [loco](https://github.com/kootenpv/loco) for help with ssh forwarding. It can be used to share ports 5000 and 7000 on remote locally at the same ports:

```
pip install loco

loco listen SSHINFO -r 5000 -r 7000
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** It can be done using *Parallel Execution* by `xargs -P 0`.

Create a file for binding the ports e.g.

```
localhost:8080:localhost:8080
localhost:9090:localhost:8080
```

then run

```
xargs -P 0  -I xxx ssh -vNTCL xxx <REMOTE>  < port-forward
```

or you can do a **one-liner**

```
echo localhost:{8080,9090} | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/.*/&:&/' | xargs -P 0 -I xxx ssh -vNTCL xxx <REMOTE>
```

**pros** independent ssh port-forwarding, they are independent == avoiding Single Point of Failure
**cons** each ssh port-forwarding is forked separately, somehow not efficient

---

**second** it can be done using *curly brackets expansion* feature in bash

```
echo "ssh -vNTC $(echo  localhost:{10,20,30,40,50} | perl -lpe 's/[^ ]+/-L $&:$&/g') <REMOTE>"
# output
ssh -vNTC -L localhost:10:localhost:10 -L localhost:20:localhost:20 -L localhost:30:localhost:30 -L localhost:40:localhost:40 -L localhost:50:localhost:50 <REMOTE>
```

real example

```
echo "-vNTC $(echo localhost:{8080,9090} | perl -lpe 's/[^ ]+/-L $&:$&/g') gitlab" | xargs ssh
```

Forwarding `8080` and `9090` to gitlab server.

**pros** one single fork == efficient
**cons** by closing this process (`ssh`) all forwarding are closed == **Single Point of Failure**

Answer (score -1):

You can use this zsh function (probably works with bash, too)(Put it in `~/.zshrc`):

```
ashL () {
    local a=() i
    for i in "$@[2,-1]"
    do
        a+=(-L "${i}:localhost:${i}")
    done
    autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -NT "$1" "$a[@]"
}
```

Examples:

`ashL db@114.39.161.24 6480 7690 7477`

`ashL db@114.39.161.24 {6000..6050} # Forwards the whole range. This is simply shell syntax sugar.`